# How to show post_excerpt?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress themes. I am developing a theme but using `post_excerpt` it is not showing content.

```
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
              echo $recent[post_content];

}
```

Why it is not showing. But `post_content` it is showing the content.

Answer (score 0):

> Show Post Excerpt in WordPress Loop Action.

Provided you have posted some thing over to the excerpt part in the posts.

```
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);
print_r($recent_posts);
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent )
{
 echo $recent[the_excerpt];
}
```

This will work for you to show the Post Excerpt alone.

Comment: Call to a member function have_posts() on array in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\dummytheme\index.php on line 3

Comment: Share your thoughts about the code that has been modified.

Comment: It is showing last post for each iteration.Not showing for every post.

Comment: Can you post the `print_r($recent_posts)` results over to your question. I need to check that.

Comment: @VijayKumarB. Have you obtained the Output as per required :)

Answer (score 0):

> Another solution can be:

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);
     if( $recent_posts-> have_post()) : while( $recent_posts->have_post()) : $recent_posts->the_post(); ?>
       <?php echo $post->post_excerpt; ?>
       <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
 <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Call to a member function have_posts() on array in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\dummytheme\index.php on line 3

Comment: please `var_dump($recent_posts);`  and specify the output.